# How to make ext4 partition from macOS 10.13.4 High Sierra?

Tags: ext4, macos-highsierra

I need to make an `ext4` partition from macOS 10.13.4 High Sierra. The partition will be from the same disk that os x is installed in. I cannot see this option in Disk utility. Is there a terminal command or a program I can use?

Answer (score -4):

Gparted Live do this or even you can try install Gparted on your Mac

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so, with instructions on what to do.